# Unable to resolve clj-http

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen, clj-http

I want to use clj-http, so I created a project with lein with these dependencies in `project.clj`:

```
(defproject app "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:main app.core
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
          :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
            [clj-http "2.0.0"]])
```

**`src/app/core.clj`**:

```
(ns app.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as client]))

(println client)

(defn -main
  [& args])
```

when I use `lein clean && lein deps && lein run`, I get an error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: client in this context, compiling:(app/core.clj:4:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6543)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6485)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3791)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6725)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6524)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6485)
```

`lein version` output:

`Leiningen 2.5.3 on Java 1.8.0_45 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`

Did I make something wrong? I followed exactly the clj-http documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requiring `[clj-http.client :as client]` lets you refer to Vars defined in that namespace using `client` as a prefix. For example, you could say

```
(client/get "http://example.com/")
```

and get back a response.

This usage, however, is unrelated to using the symbol `client` to refer to a Var or a local, and so this isn't going to work:

```
(println client)
```

`client` is just a namespace alias registered in the current namespace, and those can't be evaluated.